# Problem escaping '>' characters when using 'Call'

Tags: batch-file, cmd, call

This code should output `>>>` without a linefeed, but it just doesn't work.

```bash
@if not "%~1"=="" (
    @goto :%~1
    @goto :eof
)
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call test.bat echonoln "^>^>^>"
pause
goto :eof

:echonoln
set text=%~2
<nul set /p a=%text%
goto :eof
```

I also tried to replace `<nul set /p a=%text%` with `echo | set /p a=%text%`.

I used jeb's method but now there is no '!'.

```bash
@echo off
if not "%~1"=="" (
    goto :%~1
)

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call "%~f0" echolnln "Hi^^!"
pause
goto :eof

:echolnln
set "text=%~2"
echo.%text%
echo.
goto :eof
```

Note: it delayed expansion must be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the escaping, it's the using in the line `set text=%~2` and `<nul set /p a=%text%`, because the special characters are handled there, too.
You can solve it by using quotes.

Change it to:

```
@echo off
if not "%~1"=="" (
    goto :%~1
)

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call "%~f0" echonoln ">>>Hi^!"
pause
goto :eof

:echonoln
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "text=%~2"
<nul set /p "=%text%"
endlocal
goto :eof
```

Btw. CALL text escaping is nasty and for some combinations it's even impossible.
It's better not to use text at all with `CALL`, it's better to use variable names instead, then there is no need for escaping in the call.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "myText=caret^ exclam! other>&|%%"
call "%~f0" echonoln myText
...

:echonoln
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p ".=!%~2!"
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about '!'?

Comment: @Yurix I added a `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion` into `:echonoln`. Btw. You only need a single caret inside quotes to escape the exclamation mark

Answer (score 0):

No need for delayed expansion. Why don't you simply use `%~2` directly instead of setting a variable?

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
if not "%~2" == "" goto :%~1
call "%~f0" echonoln "%!hello>>>&|! "
pause
goto :eof

:echonoln
<nul set /p "a=%~2"
goto :of
```

As you can see, it suppresses the `%`, but this doesn't happen if you execute it from the prompt:

```
C:\Users\Stephan\test.bat echonoln "%!hello>>>&|!% "
%!hello>>>&|!%
```

You *can* use percent signs from within the script, but it has to be double-escaped (a.k.a two escaped percent signs, which add up to FOUR of them):
`call "%~f0" echonoln "%%%%!hello>>>&|!% "` in the script outputs `%!hello>>>&|!`

Comment: but I really need delayed expansion, code that I showed is just a part, but I don't want, to make the question complex.